# In ReactJS, can I declare an array of components? and return certain component

Tags: reactjs

can I declare an array of components? and return certain component...
is this possible??

ES6:

```
import React from 'react';
import Component1 from './Component1';
import Component2 from './Component2';</br>

export default App extends React.Component {
  render() {
     const myComponents = [`<Component1 />`,`<Component2 />`];

     return (
       {myComponents.map((component, index) => {
         return component[index] === index;
       })}
    );
  }
}
```

Suggestions pls.. very much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it's possible to store them in an array. Remember that JSX is just syntactic sugar for regular Javascript — it's not magic and it's not a string, so no need to quote it.

```
const myComponents = [<Component1 />, <Component2 />];
```

The above JSX is just a shorter way of writing this:

```
var myComponents = [
  React.createElement(Component1, null),
  React.createElement(Component2, null)
];
```

The value you are returning in render is going to give you problems though.

```
mycomponents.map((component, index) => {
  // this will always return false
  // because objects are not numbers
  return component[index] === index;
});
```

This call to map is always going to return an array of false values. Which will throw errors if you try to render them.

Instead, you can just render the entire array of components.

```
return (
  <div>{ myComponents }</div>
);
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote an answer that has been marked as an accepted solution, at least leave some constructive criticism in the comments.

Comment: Sorry dude. I just misclicked the window.. my bad :(

Comment: Thanks (Y) , pal. I just realized that I returned falsey values to my map. :)